# Is it possible for unique column to contain multiple null values SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, null, unique-constraint

I want to migrate data contained in an Oracle Table A to SQL Server. The table A contains a column *CIN* with unique constraint but mutliple null values. The problem is that SQL Server is rejecting the data. Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, wasn't that just a few days ago? I had not seen that but yes, this appears to be a duplicate of that one.

Comment: yes I think it's a duplicate :) the site didn't suggest that question to me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [Filtered Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql#filtered-indexes) to remove the NULL values from consideration regarding uniqueness. You would first drop the existing `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` and then replace it with a `UNIQUE INDEX`. These two objects are essentially the same given that a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` actually exists via a `UNIQUE INDEX` (the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-column-constraint-transact-sql#arguments) for creating a column constraint states that `UNIQUE` is a "constraint that provides entity integrity for a specified column or columns by using a unique index.").

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX index_name
ON SchemaName.TableA (CIN ASC)
WHERE [CIN] IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you @srutzky for the complete documentation of the answer :)

Comment: Thank you. It works. The importan thing is to drop the UNIQUE constrain on the columns definition and than create this filtered index.